# sending synchronized signal among 3 processes

Tags: c

I'm working on signal project get a file with 0, increase to the input (ex ./count 300 sample.txt) by using sync signals p1->p2->p3->p1, after they increase number by 1, the fall in to sleep and call next one.

but I got stuck with two problems

1. how to and where to implement increasing number process, in signal handling or main( 0 -> 1 -> 2 ... input )
2. don't know how to implement with sigwait() or sigprocmask() what's the difference? . can i choose either one to guarantee that they are synchronized? or should I just use sleep?

belows are code that I've been working on so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
void sig_usr1(int signo)
{       
        char a;
        sigset_t sigset, oldset;
        sigemptyset (&oldset);
        sigemptyset (&sigset);
        sigaddset(&sigset, SIGUSR1);
        sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigset, &oldset);

        fd =open("./sample.txt",O_RDWR);
        pread (fd, a, sizeof(a));
        if (argv[0]>a)
        {a ++;
        truncate ("./sample.txt", 0);
        write(fd, a, sizeof(a));
        }
}
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{       
        int fd;
        int num=0;
        struct sigaction usrsig ;
        if(!(argv[0]>0))
                printf("insert positive integer");
        fd = open("./sample.txt",O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC);
      write(fd, num ,sizeof(num);
        pid_t child[3];

        usrsig.sa_handler =sig_usr;  // Parent
        sigemptyset(&usrsig.sa_mask); 
        usrsig1.sa_flags = 0;
        sigaction(SIGUSR1,&usrsig, 0);

        for ( i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
                child[i] = fork();
                if(child[i] == 0)
                break;
        }
        pid_t prev;
        if(i ==0)       prev = getppid();

        else            prev = child[i-1];

        kill(pid_prev, SIGUSR1)
}
```

Comment: Three named semaphores?

Comment: Keep Writing on one file by three processes without making race condition